# The problem is anything but easy

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, conjunctions

I am confused about the function of the word "but" in given sentence what "part of speech" the word "but" is in the given sentence. I actually shared my opinions with my teacher about the word "but".

My opinions: The word " but" is an adverb in the given sentence because it modifies  adjective "easy". Moreover, I looked it up in dictionary and it got something else "anything but" is also an idiom. Secondly, I checked it in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary — the same sentence is written in there and it called it as a preposition.

My teacher called it as a preposition and he also said, it can be *idiomatic adverb*. Then also gave me a sentence: The hotel is anything but satisfactory —from OLAD.  I am not sure what actually he shared but I am eagerly waiting for your clarification.

Kindly, analyze the sentence structurally and remove this confusion with your remarks. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [*but*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but): "5. *preposition* - **But** is used to mean 'except'." which is the case in your examples.

Comment: I didn't get any good explanation about my answer since this is very confusing.

Comment: There is the word "easy" in the given sentence. It's an adjective. Therefore, I'm asking you for "analysis" and its "structures" and "explanations".

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for - [*anything but*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/anything+but). Basically it modifies *easy*. Seems like your teacher was right.

Comment: Please, give me some reasons. I am not satisfied with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct.  The idiomatic expression "anything but X" means "emphatically *not* X".

> She isn't talkative.  She is **anything but talkative**.  You'll be lucky if you can get a word out of her.

It's generally not meaningful to analyze idioms with formal grammar, since they're often unique cases.  Even with similar idioms such as

> The war is **all but** over.

or

> They fed us **nothing but** tea and cake.

"but" may be classified as a preposition, but the meanings of the idioms vary.  "All but over" means it's *nearly* over.  "Nothing but tea and cake" means *only* tea and cake.  The best way to deal with these is to memorize the expressions and use them where appropriate.